Lombok - How to create a custom constructor for @SuperBuilder generic classes
I'm trying to create default constructors for generic classes annotated with Lombok's @SuperBuilder. However, the compiler throws errors saying that the constructor already exists. The default constructor works for non-generic classes, e.g:
@SuperBuilder
public class MyRegularSuperObject {
    private final String someString;
    
    protected MyRegularSuperObject(MyRegularSuperObject.MyRegularSuperObjectBuilder<?,?> b) {
        someString = b.someString;
    }
}

However, it does not work for any generic @SuperBuilder object, e.g:
@SuperBuilder
public class MyGenericSuperObject<T> {
    private final String someString;
    
    protected MyGenericSuperObject(MyGenericSuperObjectBuilder<T,?,?> b) {
        someString = b.someString;
    }
}

Throws the following exception:

error: constructor MyGenericSuperObject(MyGenericSuperObjectBuilder<T,?,?>) is already defined in class MyGenericSuperObject
@SuperBuilder
^
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class MyGenericSuperObject

I suppose this might be an issue with Lombok, but first I'd like to check if there's anything obvious I've missed which could let me define default constructors also for generic classes?

This is probably a lombok bug. The annotation processor doesn't understand that you already declared a constructor, and proceeds to declare an additional constructor.

There is a fix in the works: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/pull/3646
